# line break in a Function in Mathjax

Tags: latex, mathjax

very basic question about line break. I'm a newbie at mathjax but understand latex well. I'm using mathjax to make a quiz.

I tried to use  \\ in mathjax but it doesn't show  the line break: I'd the question to say:

If a + 10 = 2,

then what is the value of a

```
   { 
        op1: 0,
        question: function() {
            op1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

            return `If $ a + ${op1} = 2  \\ $, then what is the value of $a$`;  
        },
        answer: function() {
            return op1 * op2;
        }
      }
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since `\` is a special character in javascript string literals, you need to double them if you want an actual `\` in your string.  So you would need to use `\\\\` to get `\\` in the resulting string.  Your `\\` would just add `\`, which (together with the following space) will be the `\` control sequence, which will just add a space at the end of the expression.